# Lifetime problems on implementing function that maps over an iterator using a HashMap

Tags: rust, generic-programming, lifetime, existential-type

I tried to implement a function that maps over an iterator using a `HashMap`:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

/// Translates every element it gets using a map. In case the map does not help, it is mapped to
/// itself.
fn translate<'a, 'b, S, T>(map: &'a HashMap<T, T>, stream: S) -> impl Iterator<Item = T> + 'a + 'b
where
    S: Iterator<Item = T> + 'b,
    T: Copy + Eq + Hash,
{
    stream.map(|e: T| -> T { *map.get(&e).unwrap_or(&e) })
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f24a1655712574e89e2c972ddef08916)

I get an error message for this code:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:11:16
   |
11 |     stream.map(|e: T| -> T { *map.get(&e).unwrap_or(&e) })
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the function body at 6:14...
  --> src/lib.rs:6:14
   |
6  | fn translate<'a, 'b, S, T>(map: &'a HashMap<T, T>, stream: S) -> impl Iterator<Item = T> + 'a + 'b
   |              ^^
   = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
           expected &&std::collections::HashMap<T, T>
              found &&'a std::collections::HashMap<T, T>
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'b` as defined on the function body at 6:18...
  --> src/lib.rs:6:18
   |
6  | fn translate<'a, 'b, S, T>(map: &'a HashMap<T, T>, stream: S) -> impl Iterator<Item = T> + 'a + 'b
   |                  ^^
note: ...so that return value is valid for the call
  --> src/lib.rs:6:66
   |
6  | fn translate<'a, 'b, S, T>(map: &'a HashMap<T, T>, stream: S) -> impl Iterator<Item = T> + 'a + 'b
   |                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have not figured out what is wrong or how I can solve it.

Comment: Please include the error message that you get. Also, include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that everyone is on the same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to guess, as you didn't include a MCVE. Your code doesn't compile, with lifetime errors on the surface. The function signature you probably meant is:

```
fn translate<'a, 'b, S, T>(map: &'a HashMap<T, T>, stream: S) -> impl Iterator<Item = T> + 'a
where
    S: Iterator<Item = T> + 'b,
    T: Copy + Eq + Hash,
    'b: 'a, // Read: "'b outlives 'a"
```

As `S` might outlive your return value, and it would still be valid. 
However I do not see any advantages of this approach: A longer lifetime is always valid in place of a shorter one, you don't explicitly need to call that out. Simply use a single lifetime, like below.

```
fn translate<'a, S, T>(map: &'a HashMap<T, T>, stream: S) -> impl Iterator<Item = T> + 'a
where
    S: Iterator<Item = T> + 'a,
    T: Copy + Eq + Hash,
{
    stream.map(move |e: T| -> T { *map.get(&e).unwrap_or(&e) })
}
```

As you see, you are also missing the `move` keyword, which your closure absolutely requires. Otherwise, it might outlive your map, which is owned by the function.

Still, this function is quite dense. If you only use it in a single place, maybe don't introduce it at all, and save some headaches?

Comment: First of all: Thank you! Your solution works. Please let me detail my question to understand what I did wrong in my first try.

1. I understand the sense of `move` but why do I need it? Is not every reference (and hence the type of the parameter `map`) a copy-type?
2. Even when I modify my first solution to use the keyword `move` it still does not work. Although it works, when I replace `'b` with `'a` as well. Obviously both function parameters must live long enough. But why can't I express that the return type is of lifetime `'a + 'b`? (I supposed this to be the "cut" (set theory) of them)

Comment: 1. Yes, every reference is a copy type. Still, if you don't move `map` in the closure, you don't make sure `map` lives long enough. Of what value is a copied reference, if it is not longer valid? That's why it is forbidden. 2. `'a + `'b` means for `'a` and `'b`, just like with traits. Such an idiom is, to my knowledge, rarely used. If you really need lifetime constraints, consider expressing them in a `where` clause, like I did- that's less ambiguous from my viewpoint.